# How to use github java API (org.eclipse.egit.github.*) to search for Users by Mail

Tags: java, api, github, github-api, egit

I'm using GitHub Java API (org.eclipse.egit.github.*) and I have to search for a specific Users to assign Issues.

The problem is that I have to look for proper user by his/her **mail** and not with **userid**.

I cannot see any Search method in UserService class... any advice please?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44888187/get-github-username-through-primary-email

Comment: @assylias yep! So I have to necessarily go outside Java library and use directly ReST calls, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment this library doesn't offer this feature.
The only way is to invoke the Search User ReST Endpoint

```
/api/v3/search/users?q=$MAIL
```

and pass the email as query parameter.